# Center Image in Excel Cell

Tags: vba, excel, vbscript

The following code inserts an image into cell `a1` of an Excel workbook. Assuming that I've already established the cell width, how would I center this image in the cell? Thanks!

```
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")  

objExcel.Visible = True 
objExcel.DisplayAlerts=False

Set objWorkbook1= objExcel.Workbooks.Open("workbook.xlsx")
Set Xlsheet = objWorkbook1.Worksheets("Cover")

Xlsheet.Range("a1").Activate
Xlsheet.Pictures.Insert("logo.png")

objWorkbook1.saveAs "workbook_center.xlsx", 51
objWorkbook1.close

objExcel.DisplayAlerts=True

set objExcel = Nothing
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try aligning the cell

```
Range("A1").HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
Range("A1").VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-horizontalalignment-property-excel

Try recording a Macro with different cell alignments and see what the recorder produces which you can incorporate into your current code.

Comment: It looks like this only works for text, but not images. I was able to change two lines of code to get it to work: `Set Pic = Xlsheet.Pictures.Insert("logo.png")` and `Pic.ShapeRange.IncrementLeft 200` Adjust the number to taste.

Comment: Ah it might be the difference between an image being in the cell or on top of the cell